# Change ImageView Resource when alarmManager wakes up

Tags: android, service, timer, handler, android-view

I have an ImageView in my activity that shows an "active" symbol when a service is activated. 
After the Service has been executed the ImageView should go back to the "inactive" Symbol.

AlarManager that starts Service:

```
    context = this;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, INTENT_CODE, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNew.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
setImage(active);
```

AlarmManager:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent wakeupIntent = new Intent(context, WakeupActivity.class);
        context.startService(wakeupIntent);

    }
```

How can I make the Image change back to inactive after the service has been executed? I tried to create a new Runnable and then postDelayed(runnable, calNew.getTimeInMillis()) using a handler. Actually it didn't work, nothing happened. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "I have an ImageView that shows an "active" symbol when a service is activated" -- where? In an activity? In an app widget?

Comment: Hi there, sorry - In an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the Image change back to inactive after the service has been executed?

Step #1: Add the Android Support package to your application.

Step #2: Have your activity register a `BroadcastReceiver` with `LocalBroadcastManager` in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`.

Step #3: Have your service send a broadcast via `LocalBroadcastManager` when its work is complete, to be picked up by the activity's `BroadcastReceiver`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Intents/Local) demonstrating this technique.